# Map AngularJs QueryString with Web Api Controller Parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Here is my Angularjs Controller Code:

```
app.controller('listAdsController', ['$scope', 'myService', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, myService, $routeParams, $location) {

myService.getAdsByCategory({categoryId : $routeParams.categoryId});
$scope.totalItems = 64;

$scope.pageChanged = function () {        
    var path = $location.path();
    $location.path(path).search('page', $scope.currentPage);
};

$scope.maxSize = 10;
$scope.bigTotalItems = 175;
$scope.currentPage= 1;
$scope.itemsPerPage = 50;
}]);
```

Here in `pageChanged`function, I am trying to change my Url according to page number by using querystring like below:

> //localhost/category/property/4/house-for-rent?page=2

Here is my routing config for that Url:

```
$routeProvider.when("/category/:category/:categoryId/:urlName", {
        controller: "listAdsController",
        templateUrl: "app/views/category-ads.html"
    });
```

Now below is my Web Api 2 Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllByCategory([FromUri] int categoryId, int? page = null)
    {
       //Code
    }
```

The problem is, `page` parameter is always always `null` no matter what I am passing in it. Can you someone guide me what I am missing here?

Comment: try  Localhost/GetAllByCategory/1/2, if that works I have a pretty good explanation as to why

Comment: Your question is missing some essential parts: how does your Angular code invoke the Web API and how are the Web API routes configured? The Angular code you posted does not call the API. It only routes to a view with  template  `app/views/category-ads.html` and assigns the `listAdsController` to it (an Angular controller that is, not the Web API controller).

Comment: @venerik I am getting WebApi by using my myService

Answer (score 0):

The problem was very small. I was just passing the querystring to url but was not getting it from the `routeParam`.

The solution is:

```
$scope.categoryAds = jetService.getAllByCategory({ categoryId: $routeParams.categoryId, page: $routeParams.page });
```

You need to get `page` from the querystring pass it to your service.